# Convert Memoir Class to Koma Class

Tags: conversion

Is there a relatively painless way to convert a manuscript typeset using the Memoir class to the Koma book class? The reason is because Koma Script supports half-point font sizes out of the box whereas trying to accomplish this in Memoir is an exercise in futility. (global option ignored, extsizes not helpful,etc.)

Comment: As a user of neither of those classes, I'm not really sure what the big deal would be. AFAIK, you should just be able to swap out `memoir` for `scrbook` in the `\documentclass` call.

Comment: It depends, I think. How many `memoir` specific commands etc. have you got in the document? If the answer is 'very few', then it will be pretty easy. If the answer is' lots and lots', then it may be easy but it will probably be more work. Without knowing anything more, it is impossible to say ;).

Comment: It depends on how much of one class you're using that requires translation. Since document classes typically provide the fundamental document parameters, switching can be painful, especially if the class is comprehensive (like both [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) and [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) are).

Comment: It's possible you can define whichever `memoir`-specific commands you use into ones that make sense with `scrbook`.

Comment: Well, for one, Memoir doesn't support \lowerbacktitle, \frontmatter (I don't think) and not a few more. If someone has written a script to identify those commands that don't work--highlighting them in the code, for example--it would save a lot of busy work. I doubt that I am the first person in the history of either package who wanted to quickly make the changeover.

Comment: Best thing is to make a *copy* of your manuscript (or commit it, if you are using version control and note the revision number well) and then try it and see. I depends a bit, too, on what you mean by 'convert': emulate the default `memoir` layout? get it to continue compiling without error? emulate a custom layout built on top of `memoir` which uses `memoir`-specific macros?

Comment: Wait -- if you're using `memoir` now, why would you currently have commands that 'don't work' with it? (by the way, I'm confident `\frontmatter` works.)

Comment: Memoir works perfectly fine but I need access to half-point font sizes.

Comment: Have you considered using `fontspec`?

Comment: Switch the class and try compiling in interactive mode. TeX will tell you which things are not defined. A script would basically have to emulate TeX - what would be the point?

Comment: @cfr well, a script could run tex in nonstopmode and parse out those commands it doesn't recognize.

Comment: @cfr: Where there are substitutes in one package for another, list the substitutes; if the noncompliant code could be highlighted that would at least be a start as opposed to compile=>fail, fix, compile=>fail, fix etc.

Comment: @SeanAllred: fontspec, extsizes, anyfontsize, etc. will not reliably scale half point font sizes. Koma has this functionality built in. Do you have a link to the script whereof you speak?

Comment: @SeanAllred True. But that is pretty trivial to script anyway. Just grep the `.log`. GM Jones: you can run in nonstopmode. You don't have to fix each error before getting to the next (although sometimes it is easier).

Comment: $awesomelinuxbox> grep .log memoir.tex??

Comment: `\usepackage{scrextend}` adds support for `\KOMAoptions{fontsize=11.22bp}` or whatever, I think.

Comment: You might want to read `man grep`: `grep my-file.log '^!'` is a good start, if memory serves.

Comment: @Manuel I just checked: it does. (Sec 10.5 of Koma's manual p. 241. At least, the English version.)

Comment: @cfr Answer added.

Comment: @Manuel Excellent. (+1) I was looking the documentation up and you posted your comment in the meantime. (I couldn't remember what the package was called. Just that it existed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add support for KOMA-Script features (in particular all possible font sizes) you can add

```
\usepackage{scrextend}
```

Thanks to @cfr for her comment: *I just checked: it does. (Sec 10.5 of Koma's manual p. 241. At least, the English version.)*

Comment: This answer also responds to several questions I came across on the site where people reported problems in efforts to obtain intermediate font point sizes.

Comment: That's true. In any case, if your question is only related to font size, you should reword it, and then it should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: My question was not solely related to font size. I was hoping that there was a package or a pandoc-type solution to convert Memoir (or other book class variants) to the Koma-script book class. The current document I'm working on has this font size issue but I'd like to know globally.

Comment: In that case I think you should reword the question a little bit (for future reference).